# Excel VBA : If the selected cell is empty

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement

Hope you're all doing well.

So I am working on a macro on excel, the goal is to copy and paste an x cell of the last column added, knowing that each day a column is added till the Column "AX" is reached .

So the idea I had, is to check if the last column (AX) is empty, if yes then I move left with 3 columns, then do again the same thing if it's empty move another time with 3 columns to the left, untill It finds a full cell, then do the copy and paste process.

The problem Is that I don't know how to define the loop to keep doing the check untill it finds a full cell.

My code to the moment :

```
Sub Test_FM()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
x = 0
Sheets("Test FM").Select
Range("AX9").Select
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
Range("AX9").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=x).Activate
x = x - 3
Range("AX9").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=x, columnoffset:=0).Activate
ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
Range("AX9").Select
Range("AX9").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=x, columnoffset:=0).Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DR 02").Select
Range("M19").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial

ElseIf 
IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
Sheets("Test FM").Select
Range("AX9").Select
Range("AX9").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=x, columnoffset:=0).Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DR 02").Select
Range("M19").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
End IF
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset)

```vb
Sub Test_FM()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet, cell As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Test FM")
    Set wsTarget = wb.Sheets("DR 02")

    Set cell = ws.Range("AX9")
    Do While Len(cell.Value) = 0
        If cell.Column < 4 Then Exit Do
        Set cell = cell.Offset(0, -3) ' move 3 cols to left
    Loop

    If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "All columns empty up to " & cell.Address, vbCritical
    Else
        cell.Copy
        wsTarget.Range("M19").PasteSpecial
        MsgBox cell.Address & " copied to M19 on " & wsTarget.Name, vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi CDP1802 

What an amazing code.

I will try it and update you if it works. 

Thank you, I appreciate your help